# SQL Server cast string to datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a string `010910` in `ddMMyy` format thatI have to cast this string a SQL Server datetime datatype, like `2010-09-01 00:00:00.000`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Google "sql server cast string to datetime". The first hit is the answer you need.

Comment: @Pondlife - I don't think there is an option answer for the format I'm working with.

Comment: That's correct, but hopefully it's obvious that if you know the supported formats, the only thing you need to do is convert your own format to a supported one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(right(s, 2) + left(s,4) as datetime)
FROM (SELECT '010910' s) a
```

Answer (score 5):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(6)
SELECT  @String = '010910'

SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@String,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@String, 3, 2) + '/' + RIGHT(@String,2),3)
```

Have a look at [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) and [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Your's works perfectly but I think t-clausen.dk's answer is more precise and short.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the bits out using `SUBSTRING` and put them back together by concatenating.